# Custom JodaTime serializer using Play Framework's JSON library?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, deserialization, playframework-2.1

How do I implement a custom JodaTime's DateTime serializer/deserializer for JSON? I'm inclined to use the Play Framework's JSON library (2.1.1). There is a default DateTime serializer, but it uses `dt.getMillis` instead of `.toString` which would return an ISO compliant String.

Writing `Reads[T]` and `Writes[T]` for case classes seems fairly straightforward, but I can't figure out how to do the same for `DateTime`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use Play 2.3.7 and define in companion object implicit reads/writes with string pattern:

```
case class User(username:String, birthday:org.joda.time.DateTime)

object User {
  implicit val yourJodaDateReads = Reads.jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
  implicit val yourJodaDateWrites = Writes.jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code, but it doesn't work for me, I've created a new [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462673/how-to-use-joda-datetime-with-play-json) about this issue

Comment: In your code use `Json.fromJson[User](value)` instead of `Json.fromJson(value)`. More details see in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31516048/4081054) to your post.

Comment: Did you mean `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` instead of `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`?

Comment: @JakeGreene: Well, it depends of the time string format defined in your project. In my app I used `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`.

Comment: Yeah this didn't work for me either, I had to use the code in @Guillaume's post

Answer (score 25):

> There is a default DateTime serializer, but it uses dt.getMillis instead of .toString which would return an ISO compliant String.

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala), `Reads.jodaDateReads` already handles both numbers and strings using `DateTimeFormatter.forPattern`. If you want to handle ISO8601 string, just replace it with `ISODateTimeFormat`:

```
  implicit val jodaISODateReads: Reads[org.joda.time.DateTime] = new Reads[org.joda.time.DateTime] {
    import org.joda.time.DateTime

    val df = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[DateTime] = json match {
      case JsNumber(d) => JsSuccess(new DateTime(d.toLong))
      case JsString(s) => parseDate(s) match {
        case Some(d) => JsSuccess(d)
        case None => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(ValidationError("validate.error.expected.date.isoformat", "ISO8601"))))
      }
      case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(ValidationError("validate.error.expected.date"))))
    }

    private def parseDate(input: String): Option[DateTime] =
      scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[DateTime] opt (DateTime.parse(input, df))

  }
```

(simplify as desired, e.g. remove number handling)

```
  implicit val jodaDateWrites: Writes[org.joda.time.DateTime] = new Writes[org.joda.time.DateTime] {
    def writes(d: org.joda.time.DateTime): JsValue = JsString(d.toString())
  }
```

Comment: Great answer. I had to make a modification to get it working though. 'pattern' is referred to but is not in scope. I replaced it with 'df'.  Was that your intention?

Comment: @justinhj Thanks! `df` doesn't make sense there, actually. I fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

Another, perhaps simpler, solution would be to do a map, for example:

```
case class GoogleDoc(id: String, etag: String, created: LocalDateTime)

object GoogleDoc {
  import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
  import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat

  implicit val googleDocReads: Reads[GoogleDoc] = (
      (__ \ "id").read[String] ~
      (__ \ "etag").read[String] ~
      (__ \ "createdDate").read[String].map[LocalDateTime](x => LocalDateTime.parse(x, ISODateTimeFormat.basicdDateTime()))
  )(GoogleDoc)
}
```

### UPDATE

If you had a recurring need for this conversion, then you could create your own implicit conversion, it is only a couple of lines of code:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat

implicit val readsJodaLocalDateTime = Reads[LocalDateTime](js =>
  js.validate[String].map[LocalDateTime](dtString =>
    LocalDateTime.parse(dtString, ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTime())
  )
)
```