# How to use Joda DateTime with Play Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, jodatime

I'm developing a Play application, and I'm trying to use a Joda DateTime object into my case class.

```
package model

import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.libs.json._

case class User(name: String, created: DateTime)

object User {
  implicit val yourJodaDateReads = Reads.jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
  implicit val yourJodaDateWrites = Writes.jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'")
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val value = Json.parse("{ \"name\" : \"hello\" , \"created\" : \"2015-07-16T20:32:04.046+02:00\" }")

  println(Json.toJson(new User("user", new DateTime())))
  println(Json.fromJson(value))
 }
}
```

Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255504/custom-jodatime-serializer-using-play-frameworks-json-library/28586712#28586712), I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(18, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 /activator-1.3.2/notifier-app/app/model/Test.scala:18: ambiguous implicit    values:
 both value yourJodaDateReads in object User of type => play.api.libs.json.Reads[org.joda.time.DateTime]
    and value userFormat in object User of type => play.api.libs.json.OFormat[model.User]
```

I'm using Activator 1.3.2 and Play 2.3.8.

Could you please advice me ?

Thanks in advance.

**update**

I understand there is a conflict with the implicit value in *play.api.libs.json.Reads*

```
implicit val DefaultJodaDateReads = jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom JodaTime serializer using Play Framework's JSON library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255504/custom-jodatime-serializer-using-play-frameworks-json-library)

Comment: Please read my post instead of replying a bad response. I've quoted this link because my code is based on this thread..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Expecting a better alternative, here my workaround:

```
val dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

val jodaDateReads = Reads[DateTime](js =>
  js.validate[String].map[DateTime](dtString =>
    DateTime.parse(dtString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat))
  )
)

val jodaDateWrites: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
  def writes(d: DateTime): JsValue = JsString(d.toString())
}

val userReads: Reads[User] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "created").read[DateTime](jodaDateReads)
  )(User.apply _)

val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
   (JsPath \ "created").write[DateTime](jodaDateWrites)
  )(unlift(User.unapply))

implicit val userFormat: Format[User] = Format(userReads, userWrites)
```

Comment: Finally I understood Play Format.

Answer (score 24):

In play 2.6, the canonical way to serialize/deserialize joda DateTime json is by using the [play-json-joda](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/tree/a3c7748a2e42290c8a12c8e01fc70bc0a8f54aa3/play-json-joda/src) library. [Import the library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json-joda_2.11/2.6.0-RC1) by updating your `build.sbt`. Then create json reader and json writers like this :

```
import play.api.libs.json.JodaWrites
implicit val dateTimeWriter: Writes[DateTime] = JodaWrites.jodaDateWrites("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
import play.api.libs.json.JodaReads
implicit val dateTimeJsReader = JodaReads.jodaDateReads("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Comment: Play 2.6 has so many nice features, i keep finding little quality of life changes like this

Comment: Make sure the [`DateTimeFormat`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) pattern argument matches the `String` you're reading; e.g. in my case (Postgres > Django > Play), the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` failed, but `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"` worked .

Answer (score 6):

Try these:

```
implicit val dateWrites = jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
implicit val dateReads = jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala#L411

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L645

Answer (score 6):

I know this question has been answered for a while, but I found a more concise answer

```
val pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
implicit val dateFormat = Format[DateTime](Reads.jodaDateReads(pattern), Writes.jodaDateWrites(pattern))
implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
```

Comment: this seems deprecated now.

Comment: Could be. I think I was using this with 2.6.7:

`"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the `User` type in `Json.toJson` and `Json.fromJson` functions. Instead of

```
println(Json.toJson(new User("user", new DateTime())))
println(Json.fromJson(value))
```

try:

```
println(Json.toJson[User](new User("user", new DateTime())))
println(Json.fromJson[User](value))
```

When you set the type explicitly framework will know what reads/writes to use.

**Update:**
It is not necessarily to set type for `Json.toJson` function because you pass `User` object as function argument and framework determines the type in runtime.
But for `Json.fromJson[User]` you must set the type, otherwise framework doesn't know type of the object you want to read.